# I have created an Android Map API key for V2, can't display a map

Tags: android, google-maps

I have created a Google API key for version two and used that in the manifest, but I'm unable to display map on the device.

I have followed everything provided in google map documentation. also I used [this link](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw).

**MainActivity.java.**

package com.example.googlenewmap;

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
        static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
        static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
        private GoogleMap map;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            if (map != null) {
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                        .title("Hamburg"));
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(KIEL)
                        .title("Kiel")
                        .snippet("Kiel")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
            }

        }

    }
```

**Manifest File**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.googlenewmap"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="14"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <permission
            android:name="com.example.googlenewmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlenewmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

        <!-- Copied from Google Maps Library/AndroidManifest.xml. -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

        <!-- External storage for caching. -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <!-- My Location -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
        <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->

        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />
        <!-- End of copy. -->

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
            <!--
             ** You need to replace the key below with your own key. **
             The example key below will not be accepted because it is not linked to the
             certificate which you will use to sign this application.
             See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start
             for instructions on how to get your own key.
            -->

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="api key" />

            <activity
                android:name="com.example.googlenewmap.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What's your layout XML file looks like? What's the error you are getting?

Comment: no need to extend `FragmentActivity` extend standard `Activity`. no need to use `SupportMapFragment`. use `MapFragment`. since your minsdk is 14 not 11 and below

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for reply but i used this already but that was not working

Comment: @ErNitinRoyalKshatriya if it crashes post the stacktrace and also do as suggested in the comment

Comment: You have generated apk in debug mode or its a signed apk? If its a signed one you have to regenerate the api key using your project key. Also make sure you have select proper Services from the api console.

Answer (score 1):

What key you are using?

There  are two types of keys debug key and release key. While signing apk, you want to use release key. For that you want to compare that with signed apk

Step 1:

Say for example your apk name is A and you are signing and creating a keystore for A.apk ie A.keystore will be created in some drive location.Let's consider it in E drive.

step 2:

Now locate to jdk in C drive(Considering for windows and assigning C drive)

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore E:\A.keystore -alias A

So it will create SHA-1 finger print

Debug key is normal which you extract as usual.

Comment: Okay! Let me try! this Shadow

Comment: not able to get keystore file related to app can you please tell me where i'll get it

Comment: keystore file is were you are creating custom signed apk.file->export->Android->export android application->particular project name>skip to next-> then browse location and extend with .keystore and fill with password and some requirements etc.So compare that keystore with maps.

Comment: use create new keystore->Location of keystore to get stored say C:/A.keystore and then give password and confirm password(remember this) then in next page some veriffication like name, certification etc given fill it and click ok, it wl generate keystore at C:/A.keystore location

Comment: it's your choice.everything is just verification fill as your requirement.it's just formal and for year give 25 yrs(max)

Comment: actually i was not taking a default key that is why i was not unable to create a api key